# Access the variable scope of another nodejs process (in a required file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, scope, require

I'm stuck with something that seem impossible at first sight:

I have two scripts running in parallel:

- my application server `npm run start-server`
- my automatic documentation `npm run documentation-auto`

My server as a `models.js` file which reference a class with custom dynamic models inside.

I would like to access that file with the class instanciated in the server process (with the models from the app server)

---

File structure:

```
// user-model.js
require('models');

models.registerModel(
    'user', // modelName
    { firstName: String, lastName: String } // model
);
```

```
// models.js

module.exports = class {
    registerModel(name, model) {
        this[name] = model;
    }
}
```

**documentation-auto.js (another process)**

```
// documentation-auto.js
const models = require('../../other-app/models');
console.log(Object.keys(models)) // => registerModel (but no user :( )
```

Is it possible ? I've searched over but found nothing...

Comment: Your 2 application are independant, they cannot share variables like that. You are in a problematic of IPC (Inter-Process Communication). The easier there, In my opinion, would be to make the server write a file that you can watch from documentation-auto.js . For example write a `models.json`  and in documentation-auto.js use fs.watch on this file, to reload each time it is modified by the server process.

Comment: Yess, not a bad idea !  Can be a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

The 2 applications are running independently and you cannot share variables between 2 independent applications. For inter process communication there is a npm module called `node-ipc`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc

This can serve your need

Comment: Hi, I don't think that will work for my use case, because I need to access a class content. Corect me if I'm wrong.